# hasOwnProperty not working in array of objects, combining objects

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build an array of objects but combining similar properties and adding their values together. So many `x` array should be turned into `y` array of objects. It must be an array of objects and not just an array

```
 var x = [
    {"2018-09-13": "100"},
    {"2018-09-14": "50"},
    {"2018-09-14": "50"},
    {"2018-09-15": "100"}
 ];
```

Desired result

```
 var y = [
    {"2018-09-13": "100"},
    {"2018-09-14": "50,50"},
    {"2018-09-15": "100"}
 ];
```

Here is the function I'm running to add them together but does not work. I believe it has something to do with the array index causing a problem with the `hasOwnProperty` method

```
var z = [];

x.forEach((item) => {
    for(var date in item) {
        if(z.hasOwnProperty(date)) {
            z[date] +=  "," + item[date];
           } else {
            z.push({[date]: item[date]});
           }
         }
    })


console.log(z)
```

Comment: The reason this isn't working is that the only "own properties" z has are numerical indexes (none at first, then `0` when you first push an object onto it, then `1` as well when you next push, and so on).

I can't think of a simple implementation, but you need to instead loop through `z` (probably with `forEach`, and if you find an item with a key of `date`, append the `,` and new value to the corresponding string value. If you haven't found one by the time you've got to the end of `z`, then push a new object on as you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `z` is an *array*, so if you use it like an array, it will never pass your `hasOwnProperty` test, because arrays have *numeric* indicies, not date string indicies. Instead of using an array, try `reduce`ing into an object (from which you can use standard property lookup), and then get that object's values at the end to turn it back into an array. You can use `Object.entries` to get the key and value at once - since the objects only have one key-value pair, there's no need to use a `for..in` loop.

```js
const x = [
  {"2018-09-13": "100"},
  {"2018-09-14": "50"},
  {"2018-09-14": "50"},
  {"2018-09-15": "100"}
];
const y = Object.values(x.reduce((a, obj) => {
  const [[key, val]] = Object.entries(obj);
  if (!a[key]) a[key] = { [key] : val };
  else a[key][key] += ',' + val;
  return a;
}, {}));
console.log(y);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group the array by reducing it and push the value to the accumulator only if the key is not found, if it's found just update the value ...

```js
var array = [{
    "2018-09-13": "100"
  },
  {
    "2018-09-14": "50"
  },
  {
    "2018-09-14": "50"
  },
  {
    "2018-09-15": "100"
  }
];

var grouped = array.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  var old = null;
  let key = Object.keys(obj)[0]
  old = acc.find(item => key == Object.keys(item)[0]);
  if (!old) {
    acc.push(obj);
  } else {
    old[key] += `, ${obj[key]}`;
  }
  
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(grouped);
```